# Given $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that $y^T A y \geq 0$ for any $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, does $x^TAx=0$ imply $Ax=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, roots, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

Given $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that $y^T A y \geq 0$ for any $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, does $x^TAx=0$ imply $Ax=0$?

I think i have proven it in the case where $A$ is symmetric (so $A$ is positive semidefinite), but does it hold in this more general setting?

Comment: have you tried a few numerical experiments with an asymmetric matrix?

Comment: Quadratic forms with non-symmetric matrices are silly, as the skew-symmetric part contributes nothing.

Comment: Take $A$ to be the zero matrix to arrive at a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other words, is it possible for a linear map to transform a nonzero vector $x$ into a vector that is orthogonal to $x$? Asked this way, the answer is trivially yes (that is, the answer to your initial question is no).

It's even possible for the linear map to transform **every** nonzero vector into an orthogonal one: for instance in two dimensions, a rotation of angle $\pi/2$.

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

Then

$$x^TAx=\begin{pmatrix}x_1 &x_2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x_1 &x_2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-x_2 \\ x_1\end{pmatrix}=0$$

Comment: Thanks for the nice an intuitive answer Jean :)

Answer (score 0):

it is only true for positive definite matricies, whose definition are exactly :
$$x^TAx>0 \text{ if }x\neq 0 $$

This is explained by the fact that if the matrix is only positive semi definite, you only have : $$\lambda\in Sp(A)\Rightarrow \lambda \geq 0 $$